# Splash Screen on AsyncTask&Maps

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

When I launch my app it submit a query to the db through AsyncTask class. While the app get data I got a white screen and, when the comunication with db is finisched will show a map with all the marker got from the server. I'm wondering if there is a way to show a splash screen using onProgressUpdate. Or if there is a better way to show a splash screen. The image that I choose is a jpeg file.

Comment: show codes what you do

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this , modify for yours - it works fine for me for same types of problem .

private class Waiter extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // do your background job like load Map 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

         }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        //Show Map here or pass Map Activity after parsing completion 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply but I think is not what I need. Below you can find the code for the comunication with db and all the stuff for the map. But I don't know if it's possible show a splash-screen by onProgressUpdate or not.. And how can i do it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible (untested) solution, have a SplashActivity.java that passes the map to your MainActivity.java that then parse and display the map:

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new AsyncTaskRunner.execute();
    }

    public void mapsRetrieved(List<Map<String, Double>> maps) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //adjust class name as needed
        intent.putExtra("maps", maps);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, List<Map<String, Double>>> {
    //YOUR CODE
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, Double>> maps) {
            mapsRetrieved(maps);
        }
    }
}
```

In the activity_splash.xml, import the .jpeg as a drawable asset and replace *{YOUR_BACKGROUND_HERE}*

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
<!-- REPLACE {YOUR_BACKGROUND_HERE} -->
android:background="@drawable/{YOUR_BACKGROUND_HERE}"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.daose.watinfo.SplashActivity"/>
```

You can retrieve the map like so

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class EventListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        List<Map<String, Double>> maps = (List<Map<String, Double>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("maps");
        //YOUR ORIGINAL POST-EXECUTE CODE BELOW
    }
}
```

Then, in your AndroidManifest.xml, change what activity gets launched when the app opens.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</application>
```